# Maven - external xml file with dependencies

Tags: java, maven

I want to divide my dependencies into multiple `xml` files for easier management and better readability.
It means that my `pom.xml` should be able to reference a external local `xml` file (**not external `jar`!**) with dependencies list to include.
I also have to mention that I don;t want multiple `pom.xml` files. Just a `xml` file with dependencies to include.
It's possible at `gradle` build system using: `apply from: project.file('gradle/build_default.gradle')` syntax.
Is there something equivalent or similar for `maven`?

Comment: Simple answer to this. It is not possible. The question what exactly do you need to easier management ?

Comment: You can inherit dependencies from parent pom.xml.

Comment: Usually you shouldn't inherit dependencies.

Comment: I have a long applicative modules list of my team that I would like to keep separated from the main pom.xml to keep the pom.xml smaller and more readable

Comment: Module list? you wrote dependencies... ? You might go with a single/multiple bom files ...etc ... Can you give some examples...

Comment: The dependencies are for applicative separated modules.

Answer (score 2):

As khmarbaise already said:

This cannot be done. There is no mechanism for inclusion of XML into a POM.